# STARTTSL на gmail.com, или "smtp авторизация через сокеты".

Tags: smtp, сокет, gmail

Собственно сабж, как пройти этот STARTTSL на сокетах?
Сервер говорит: Ready to STARTSL, я шлю ему "STARTSL\r\n", а что потом нужно? Почитал английскую вики, что-то не дошло до меня.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте RFC-2487 http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2487.html